# Value of variable on recursive calling of a function

Tags: c++, c, function, parameter-passing

Consider the function

```
void solve(int arr[],int ind,int sum,int n,int count)
{
    if(ind==n){
          if(sum>max)
              max=sum;
      }
      else{
          sum+=arr[ind];//sum
          if(ind==n-1)
            solve(arr,ind+1,sum,n,1);//1st call
          if(ind==n-2 && count>1)
            solve(arr,ind+2,sum,n,1);//2nd call
          if(ind<n-1 && count<2){
              count++;
              solve(arr,ind+1,sum,n,count);//3rd call
          }
          if(ind<n-2)
              solve(arr,ind+2,sum,n,1);//4th call
          if(ind<n-3)
              solve(arr,ind+3,sum,n,1);//5th call
      }
}
```

I have no problem about the logic but am confused about the passing of the variables.I am not able to make out whether the integer `sum+=arr[ind] //sum` is passed as the same variable in every call or is it updated after every call of the function?

Comment: Thnx..I got the answer I gues...but @user3386109 what do you mean by c++ answer....is it different in c?

Comment: References are a C++ feature. In C, you would use a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum` is passed by value, so the value won't be updated. The following 5 `solve` calls will be passed with the same `sum` value.

If you want `sum` to be updated after each call, you should pass it by reference: `void solve(int arr[],int ind,int &sum,int n,int count)`

Answer (score 1):

The value of `sum` is updated  but `locally` everytime the function `solve` gets called.You can visualize this by printing the value of sum inside the function definition.

See the below example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void call(int);
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    call(5);
    return 0;
}
void call(int sum)
{
    if(sum>15)
      return;
    printf("%d ",sum);
    sum+=5;
    call(sum);

}
```

The o/p is `5 10 15` .

May be this helps you to visualize more clearly.